# Using PUT to update can add entries but cannot remove entries

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, dbcontext

```
[HttpPut("edit/{id}")]
        //[Route("api/{controller}/edit/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutOrder(int id, Order order)
        {
            if (id != order.OrderID)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            try
            {

                _context.Orders.Update(order);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!DispatchRequestExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }
```

As per title, why is that so? So there is a list of order items in a table of a selected order, where I can delete and add more entries and click submit to make the changes. Currently I can add but cannot remove entries after submission. How do I make the removal of entries work too?

I can already make orders and delete orders. But I am now creating a functionality to edit the order and change the fields within it, such as order items. If I edit an order and add more order items it works, but not when I remove some order items which was there initially. The changes made from editing are made on clicking the submit button, not on clicking the remove button to remove an order item from the table or adding another item. How can I do it? Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any remove command in this function. Use this if you want to remove entity.

```
_context.YourTable.Remove(YourEntity);
```